# Get xml values with xsl using fop from certain positions looping

Tags: xml, loops, xslt, apache-fop

here is my xsl (part):

```
<xsl:template name="while">
    <xsl:variable name="VALUE">
        <xsl:value-of select="instData" />
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:if test="VALUE=''">
        <xsl:variable name="next_year" select="next_year+1" />
        <xsl:call-template name="while"/>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/elements">

<xsl:for-each select="values">

<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="(instData != '')">

    <circle cx="{x_coord}" cy="{instData}" r="5" stroke="black" stroke-width="0" fill="{$var_color_instDataCircle}" />

    <xsl:variable name="act_year" select="position()" />
    <xsl:variable name="next_year" select="position()+1" />
    <xsl:variable name="act_x" select="x_coord" />
    <xsl:variable name="act_y" select="instData" />



    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="next_year/instData = ''">
            <xsl:call-template name="while"/>
        </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:variable name="next_x" select="next_year/x_coord" />
        <xsl:variable name="next_y" select="next_year/instData" />
        <line x1="{$act_x}" y1="{$act_y}" x2="{$next_x}" y2="{$next_y}" style="stroke:black;stroke-width:5;" /> 
    </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>

    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>

    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>

</for:each>


</xsl:template>
```

Here is an xml example

```
<elements> 
   <values>
    <year>2015</year>
    <x_coord>88</x_coord>
    <instData></instData>
   </values>
   <values>
    <year>2016</year>
    <x_coord>188</x_coord>
    <instData></instData>
   </values>
   <values>
    <year>2017</year>
    <x_coord>288</x_coord>
    <instData>50</instData>
   </values>
    <values>
    <year>2018</year>
    <x_coord>388</x_coord>
    <instData></instData>
   </values>
   <values>
    <year>2019</year>
    <x_coord>488</x_coord>
    <instData></instData>
   </values>
   <values>
    <year>2020</year>
    <x_coord>588</x_coord>
    <instData>100</instData>
   </values>
   <values>
    <year>2021</year>
    <x_coord>688</x_coord>
    <instData>40</instData>
   </values>
   <values>
    <year>2022</year>
    <x_coord>788</x_coord>
    <instData></instData>
   </values>
 </elements>
```

The point that I try to achieve is to draw a line of the instData values. 
I get the first point by looping with for-each and than I have the xsl:choose to search for the next value if there is. Get those x_coord and instData values as the second part of the line (x_coord for x2 and instData for y2). If there is only 1 instData than I just draw a point(that part works since I draw all the points in the for-each beforehand).
I can't get the values of the next_x and next_y, the x2 part. 
Any idea on how to get this to work?

Thanks for all your help.

Comment: What is the intended result of this process? -- P.S. I cannot make head or tails of your code. But it probably doesn't matter.

Comment: Draw a line from x1=act_x,  y1=act_y to x2=next_x, y2=next_y
... get the next_x and next_y with a while "loop" ...  code works with the exception on the draw line values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand this correctly, you could do simply:

```
<xsl:template match="elements">
    <root>
        <xsl:for-each select="values[string(instData)]">
            <xsl:variable name="next" select="following-sibling::values[string(instData)][1]" />
            <xsl:if test="$next">
                <line x1="{x_coord}" y1="{instData}" x2="{$next/x_coord}" y2="{$next/instData}" /> 
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </root>
</xsl:template>
```

to get:

```
<root>
  <line x1="288" y1="50" x2="588" y2="100"/>
  <line x1="588" y1="100" x2="688" y2="40"/>
</root>
```

---

P.S. XSLT is a declarative language: `xsl:for-each` is not a loop, and there is no `while` because it's not needed.

Comment: It looks like it but I get the error that #STRING cannot be converted into NodeList

Comment: could you look at this:
       `<xsl:for-each select="instData">
            <xsl:variable name="next" select="following-sibling::instData[1]" />
            <xsl:if test="$next">
                <line x1="{x_coord}" y1="{instData}" x2="{$next/x_coord}" y2="{$next/instData}" style="stroke:black;stroke-width:5;" /> 
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>`
Can I alter it like this? I need it raw with out template or top levels

Comment: @Viking You can see it working - without error - here: http://xsltransform.net/jxDigTP  -- There is no such thing as "without template" in XSLT. You must have at least one template to produce any output. The template establishes a context. Since I don't know in which context you are, I cannot tell what your code will do. Though I am pretty sure the `instData` nodes are not siblings of each other.

Comment: I have a template already and this code is used in a loop that points to the lvl of instData, so I just need the values. The structure is as given above but before this code there is the template and a for-each "values" loop. 
So I need to go only to instData since the rest is done beforehand

Comment: You need to edit your question and post a [mcve]. I cannot integrate my suggestion into your code (esp. when I cannot see it).

Comment: The structure now is corrected. I added the template and the for:each loop like I have them. Sorry for not doing so in the first place

Comment: I am afraid not. Your template is a named template, and it does not have a context. I *think* you can replace your `xsl:for-each` with mine, but I cannot say for sure. Please review the link in my previous comment.

Comment: Good. BTW, this looks like you're drawing using SVG. If so, wouldn't it be simpler to use a single `path` instead of multiple `line`s?